# removing columns equal to 0 from multiple data frames in a list; lapply not actually removing columns when applying function to a list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of three data frames that are similar (same number of columns but different number of rows), and were split from a larger data set.
Here is some example code to make three data frames and put them in a list. It is really hard to make an exact replicate of my data since the files are so large (over 400 columns and the first 6 columns are not numerical)

```
a <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1)
b <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
c <- c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1)
d <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
e <- c(1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1)
f <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
g <- c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
h <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
i <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
j <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0)
k <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
l <- c(1,0,1,0,1)
m <- c(1,0,1,0,0)
n <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
o <- c(1,0,1,0,1)

df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
df2 <- data.frame(g,h,i,j)
df3 <- data.frame(k,l,m,n,o)
my.list <- list(df1,df2,df3)
```

I am looking to remove all the columns in each data frame whose total == 0. The code is below:

```
list2 <- lapply(my.list, function(x) {x[, colSums(x) != 0];x})
list2 <- lapply(my.list, function(x) {x[, colSums(x != 0) > 0];x})
```

Both of the above codes will run, but neither actually remove the columns == 0. 
I am not sure why that is, any tips are greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps `x[, colSums(x) != 0]` instead of `x[, colSums(x != 0) > 0]`?

Comment: Moving the parentheses returned the error: Error in colSums(x) : 'x' must be numeric. I believe I fixed the code, but do you have any input for the new problem I have run into in the edit above?

Comment: The reason why you had the error message was that you had columns which were not in numeric. For the new question, I have no idea. Please remember that you need to provide a minimal reproducible data and a running code. SO users are happy to help you, but they are all busy people. Nobody wants to create a sample data. Would you please help others by providing the requested things above?

Comment: okay, Ill work on some example code, thanks

Comment: @jazzurro I have provided some sample code if you are able to give me any feedback, Thanks!

Comment: Remove `;x` in `lapply(my.list, function(x) {x[, colSums(x) != 0];x})`.

Comment: gosh, see I knew it was something simple! thanks so much for your help!

Comment: No problem. I am glad that you can now move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP found a solution by exchanging comments with me. But I wanna drop the following. In `lapply(my.list, function(x) {x[, colSums(x) != 0];x})`, the OP was asking R to do two things. The first thing was subsetting each data frame in `my.list`. The second thing was showing each data frame. I think he thought that each data frame was updated after subsetting columns. But he was simply asking R to show each data frame as it is in the second command. So R was showing the result for the second command. (On the surface, he did not see any change.) If I follow his way, I would do something like this.

```
lapply(my.list, function(x) {foo <- x[, colSums(x) != 0]; foo})
```

He wanted to create a temporary object in the anonymous function and return the object. Alternatively, he wanted to do the following.

```
lapply(my.list, function(x) x[, colSums(x) != 0])
```

For each data frame in `my.list`, run a logical check for each column. If `colSums(x) != 0` is TRUE, keep the column. Otherwise remove it. Hope this will help future readers.

```
[[1]]
   a c e
1  0 1 1
2  1 0 1
3  0 1 1
4  1 1 1
5  0 1 0
6  0 1 1
7  0 1 0
8  0 1 1
9  0 1 0
10 1 1 1
11 0 0 1
12 1 1 1

[[2]]
   g i j
1  1 1 0
2  0 0 0
3  1 0 0
4  0 0 0
5  1 0 1
6  1 0 1
7  1 0 1
8  1 0 1
9  1 0 1
10 1 0 0

[[3]]
  l m o
1 1 1 1
2 0 0 0
3 1 1 1
4 0 0 0
5 1 0 1
```